# Unable to find frames from the numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Currently working on the dataset which is in `.mat` file format. In order to get the frames, I have converted the video into numpy array using `loadmat` function. Not able to figure out how to find frames from the given numpy array?

The output of the file after loadmat function is as follows:

```
{'siz': array([[60., 80., 26.]]),
 'vid': array([[108, 113, 106, ...,  99, 105, 107],
    [107, 105, 105, ..., 104, 109, 118],
    [119, 122, 120, ..., 125, 128, 136],
    ...,
    [123, 123, 124, ..., 121, 117, 118],
    [119, 122, 118, ..., 117, 120, 126],
    [124, 122, 123, ..., 120, 122, 118]], dtype=uint8)}
```

Comment: Looks like a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to me. At a guess your frames are in `dict['vid']`

Comment: `loadmat` returns a `dict`.  `data[siz]` should be the first array, `data['vid']` the second.

Answer (score 1):

I appears as though the frames are part of the "vid" key in the dict which i labelled `x` in the example.

I presume that array was a `numpy array`.

So it looks like this:

```py
from numpy import *

x = {'siz': array([[60., 80., 26.]]),
 'vid': array([[108, 113, 106,   99, 105, 107],
    [107, 105, 105,  104, 109, 118],
    [119, 122, 120,  125, 128, 136],
    
    [123, 123, 124,  121, 117, 118],
    [119, 122, 118,  117, 120, 126],
    [124, 122, 123,  120, 122, 118]], dtype=uint8)}


frame = x['vid']

# examples
print(frame[0]) # the first frame
print(frame[5]) # the fith frame
```

return:

```
[108 113 106  99 105 107]
[124 122 123 120 122 118]
```